# GCP - Cloud Function can't find Python package from Artifact Registry in the same project

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-artifact-registry

I've been trying GCP's Artifact Registry, which is currently in alpha for Python packages.

I do the authentication via Keyring along with my service account, as explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/authentication#keyring).

I can successfully upload a package using Twine, and I can successfully download it to a local Python project by installing the following `requirements.txt`:

```
--extra-index-url https://my-region-pypi.pkg.dev/my-project/my-python-repo/simple/
my-package
```

However, when I deploy a minimal Cloud Function to the same project as my Artifact Registry, with the same `requirements.txt` shown above, the deployment fails with the following output:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: `pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement my-package (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for my-package (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

I tried with both `--extra-index-url` and just plain `--index-url`, with no difference. I also tried installing the keyring dependencies with the following `requirements.txt`:

```
--extra-index-url https://my-region-pypi.pkg.dev/my-project/my-python-repo/simple/
keyring
keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth
my-module
```

But I get the same error.

I checked the permissions for my default App Engine service account for my project, which is also used for Cloud Functions, and I can confirm that it has the Artifact Registry Reader role, so it doesn't seem to be a permissions issue.

I also tried deploying a minimal App Engine service instead of a Cloud Function, but I get the same error.

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. In the meantime we stopped using Artifact Registry and started including our compressed packages manually in our repos. It works, but it can be a little tedious.

Comment: Has there been any update on this?  I have a similar problem where I used AR to install a package (visible in cloud build logs), but its not available in the environment (doing `help('modules')` doesn't list my package either).

Comment: Same issue. But I won't go for the dirty compressed package solution, my workaround will be not using Google Cloud I guess.

Comment: Has anyone tried with the cloud functions v2 ?

Comment: Tried on the --gen2, same problem

Comment: I narrowed down the problem, I thik this is a package versioning issue from the artifact registry, I created a separate issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72155998/gcp-artifact-registry-cannot-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-when

Comment: I'm curious to know what happens if you use a SA JSON file to do the auth, if you run this [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/artifacts/print-settings/python): `gcloud artifacts print-settings python --json-key="somekey.json" --repository=REPO --location=LOCATION` pointing `somekey.json` to a serviceaccount JSON file with the right permissions for the repo. It will generate an `extra-index-url` with the auth embedded. **Do not put this in a public place as it will contain the JSON SA creds.**

Comment: just as an FYI, I tried this on my test-project, and I get a `403` error when it tries to download the package, but the logs still show that it *did* find the package as I can see the exact URL for the `.whl` file, including version, but the `403` is thrown on the download. Note that the SA I used lives in the same project as the repo, with Artifact Registry Reader permissions.

Answer (score 6):

Took me a while, but I managed to get a CF from one project to download a package from another project.

There's a couple of steps involved, one of which is as of now not documented. Doing some testing and looking at the logs helped me narrow the actual behavior down.

**1:** Have package in one project. I'll call that project `repo-project`.
Note, the package I uploaded is a simple one that just returns `42` when the only function inside is called. Any helloworld package should suffice.

**2:** Have another project for the Cloud Function. I'll call that project `cf-project`.

**3:** Create service account in either project, and give it the *Artifact Registry Reader* permission in `repo-project`. I'll call this `artifact-sa`.

**4:** **This is the undocumented step:** Give the *Cloud Build Service Account* from `cf-project` the same *Artifact Registry Reader* permission in `repo-project`. The format for the name of this account is `<PROJECT-NUMBER>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`

**5:** Not sure if this one is needed, but it's how I did it. I ran the command below pointing to a downloaded JSON version of `artfact-sa`:
`gcloud artifacts print-settings python --json-key="artifact-sa.json" --repository=REPO --location=LOCATION`
This prints out a value for `--extra-index` to put in a `requirements.txt` which includes the JSON key. I think using the keyring method mentioned by OP would also work here.
*(note I did some extra steps which are not needed, see below, to ensure the key doesn't get uploaded to any github repo attached to the code for the CF)*

**6:** Deploy the code however you like.

---

### Summary

So, to summarize, the first authentication to the repo is done with whatever SA you use (eg, in the keyring, or using the method I described above). Stupidly enough, the download itself is done with the inbuilt SA for Cloud Build from the project you are deploying the Cloud Function to (`cf-project`). IMHO this should be done by the same SA as the first.

As to how I found out the SA for Cloud Build was the issue, when I only added `artifact-sa` to `repo-project`, it *did* find the exact `.whl` file while deploying the CF in `cf-project`, with the correct version number (checking the error in the logs). It tried to download the package, but it got a `403` on said download.
I've had other scenarios where the internal usage of SA's on Google's side was a bit wonky, and the Cloud Build one is definitely a repeat offender here.

---

### Extra steps for security

I created a secondary requirements file and added that to my `.gitignore` file to make sure it doesn't get uploaded to my repo, because uploading keys is a [bad idea](https://c.tenor.com/-4CxYhRmAFUAAAAM/its-a-bad-idea-no-good.gif)

**requirements.txt**

```
-r privatereq.txt
mypythonpackage
```

**private.req.txt**

```
--extra-index-url https://_json_key_base64:[BASE64_KEY_SNIPPED]@[LOCATION]-python.pkg.dev/[REPO-PROJECT]/python-repo/simple/
```

**.gitignore**

```
*/privatereq.txt
```

Comment: step #4 is what solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

pointing the requirements to:

```
--extra-index-url https://<location>-python.pkg.dev/<project>/<repository>/simple
<package>
```

and imports in main:

```
from <package> import <module>
```

works for me.
Remember to repeat the required modules for your package in the requirements.txt (setup.cfg from packaging works only in the build-process)

Comment: strange, is your package in the same project as the cloud function ? Can you show the detail of the package ?

Answer (score 0):

This was definitely the missing piece, I thought I had to give the default service account permission on the Artifact Registry. Changing it to Cloud Build instead got me there. Didn't have to do anything other than that.