# Cannot add private python dependency to cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-artifact-registry

I am trying to deploy a python cloud function on GCP, using a python package pushed on the artifact registry of another project.

I followed the instructions [off the google cloud documentation:](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python?hl=en)

The **service account** that deploys the cloudbuild has the role: **Artifact Registry Reader**

The **error in cloudbuild:**

```sh
CESTERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-west1-python.pkg.dev/my-project-id/package-name/simple/

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement package_name==0.1.5 (from versions: none)
```

the **requirements.txt**

```sh
--extra-index-url https://us-west1-python.pkg.dev/my-project-id/package-name/simple/
package_name==0.1.5
```

the **setup.py** of the package

```py
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name="package_name",
    version="0.1.5",
    description="Python package",
    author="Benjamin BRETON",
    author_email="john.doe@gmail.com",
    url="",
    packages=["src/package_name"],
)
```

the **cloudbuild.yaml** that deploys the function.

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  args:
  - gcloud
  - functions
  - deploy
  - ${_SERVICE_NAME}
  - --region=${_REGION}
  - --source=${_REPOSITORY_PATH}
  - --trigger-http
  - --allow-unauthenticated
  - --runtime=python39
  - --memory=128MB
  - --entry-point=${_ENTRY_POINT}
  - --service-account=${_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}
  - --set-env-vars=OUTPUT_BUCKET_NAME=${_OUTPUT_BUCKET_NAME}, URL_BUCKET_NAME=${_URL_BUCKET_NAME}
options:
  logging: 'CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY'
```

I tried to run the pip install -r requirements.txt  and it works locally
If I remove the library import, the cloud function deploys and works.
I also tried to switch to the --gen2 version of cloud functions, but without luck.

People seem to have similar issues: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67490412/gcp-cloud-function-cant-find-python-package-from-artifact-registry-in-the-sam) with a different error.

Comment: What are the permission of the Cloud Build service account?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Artifact Registry Reader, and just to be sure, I gave the same role to the service account that runs the cloud function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to this problem in another question, thanks [@Edo Akse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72202715/6651736):

To grant access to the private library hosted on an artifact registry, you need to give the role **Artifact Registry Reader** to:

- The service account **running the cloudbuild**
- The **default service account of the cloud build** (in cate you ran the cloudbuild with a service account you specified yourself). This service account had the name: `<PROJECT-NUMBER>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`

You can find the `<PROJECT-NUMBER>` in the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to replicate the sample code you provided. I resolved it by changing the `package_name` version to `0.1` in the **requirements.txt** as there were no matching distribution found for `package_name==0.1.5`. The code should be:

```
package_name==0.1
```

In addition, I also update the `gcloud` components and install `beta` commands by running the following:

```
gcloud components update
gcloud components install beta
```

Let me know if you have questions or clarifications.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I have no package version 0.1, when I change to 0.1 I have a error: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement package_name==0.1 (from versions: none)

Comment: Have you run the commands above thru either cloud shell or cloud shell editor?